# ERRORES EN MI PRIMER PROYECTO

Tags: kotlin

Buenas tardes estimada comunidad Stackoverflow en español. Estoy empezando a estudiar un curso de Programación de Aplicaciones Móviles Android. Ya realicé mi primer tarea que era hacer la app "Hola Mundo". La segunda tarea es hacer una ImageView. Aplicando las ayudas y manuales de nuestro instructor escribi el código, pero me da muchos errores. Mas abajo les comparto el código y les pido un poco de ayuda. Por favor...

La tarea es hacer una invitacion para cumpleaños con 2 pantallas, una de las pantallas tendra una imagen alusiva para la ocasion y la otra pantalla tendra 6 TextView. Tambien cada pantalla tendra un boton.

```
    //Activity_main.xml
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/invitacion"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_width="425dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:text="ABRIR"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.538"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    //Activity_main2.xml
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:context=".MainActivity2">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Nombre:"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.141"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Casimiro Vaca"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.243"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Lugar:"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.438"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="En mi casa de habitacion"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.552"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Hora:"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.713"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="3:30 PM"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.787"/>
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_width="425dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:text="VOLVER"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.538"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    //MainActivity2.kt
    
    package com.lainez.imageview_wilfredolainez
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    
    class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        }
    
        val boton2 : Button! =findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    
        boton2.setOnClickListener {it: View!
            val intento1 = Intent(packageContext: this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intento1)
    }
    
    //MainActivity.kt
    
    package com.lainez.imageview_wilfredolainez
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
    
        val boton1 : Button! =findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    
        boton1.setOnClickListener { it: View!
            val intento1 = Intent(packageContext: this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            startActivity(intento1)
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que errores????

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: tal como te indicaron, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. En lugar de saludos de cortesía, describe concretamente qué errores estás teniendo. Menciónalo además en el título de la pregunta.